# rails session steal through cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, session-cookies

My question is different it's rather conceptual - As when a user login, session is created on server and it stores a unique id to client(browser) what if I copy that cryptographically signed cookie and any associate data from browser like token whatever app uses to recognize the machine, paste it or create it on another machine?

How would server recognize that? could someone Explain me as much you can? that would be a help

I tried finding the solution.

or how can I secure that? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966306/security-of-cookie-based-sessions

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, only the user-identifying token in the Rails session cookie identifies the user. By sending that token (which happens automatically on each request), the server knows who you are. Anyone having that token will be treated by the server as if it were you. This is called [Session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

There are a few things you can do to protect your user's cookies. First of all, secure your cookies by setting two flags:

- `secure` tells the browser to send that cookie only over HTTPS, so it is protected against someone reading your traffic (and your cookie).
- `HttpOnly` tells the browser to hide that cookie from Javascript, which improves protection against XSS (Cross Site Scripting). An attacker may find a way to inject some malicious Javascript, but the browser won't give it your session cookie.

On setting these flags, see [the Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html). For custom cookies it's basically:

```
cookies[:my_cookie] = { value: '...', secure: true, httponly: true}
```

For configuring the Rails session cookie, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277529/3497272).

---

Recently, I have written a middleware that sets both flags automatically to any cookie in the application. It is called [`safe_cookies`](https://github.com/makandra/safe_cookies) and we're using it in order to protect our applications.